# C Variable has incomplete initializer

Tags: c, variable-initialization, incomplete-type

I am trying to make a struct with a default value, as described here: [Default values in a C Struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749180/default-values-in-a-c-struct). However, I have this C code, inside a header file:

```
/* tokens.h */
typedef struct {
    char *ID;
    char *KEY;
    char *TYPE;
} tokens;

const struct tokens TOKENS_DFLT = {
    "id",
    "key",
    "type"
};
```

And I am getting an error on line 7 saying:

```
error: variable 'TOKENS_DFLT' has initializer but incomplete type
```

Can anyone please explain to me what this problem is and how I can fix it and prevent it in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't defined `struct tokens`. You've defined an unnamed `struct` and simultaneously `typedef`-ed it to the type name `tokens`.

If you had instead defined

```
typedef struct tokens_ {
    char *ID;
    char *KEY;
    char *TYPE;
} tokens;
```

Then you could declare your constant as *either*:

```
const struct tokens_ TOKENS_DFLT = { ... };
```

Or

```
const tokens TOKENS_DFLT = { ... };
```

As it is, you're between two stools.

Comment: now i get a warning: `Useless storage class specifier in empty declaration`

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
const struct tokens TOKENS_DFLT = {
    "id",
    "key",
    "type"
};
```

should be:

```
const tokens TOKENS_DFLT = {
    "id",
    "key",
    "type"
};
```

Since you've defined the name `tokens` to mean `struct tokens`.