# Array declaration and initialization with structs

Tags: c

I am trying to declare an array of `structs`, is it possible to initialize all array entries to a default `struct` value?

For example if my `struct` is something like

```
           typedef struct node
           {    int data;
                struct node* next;
           }node;
```

Is there a way to declare data to `4` and next to `null`? What about `0` and `null`?

Comment: If you mean "int data = 4;", the answer is NO. Not in C. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716913/default-value-for-struct-member-in-c

Comment: Ok so if it isn't possible how would I check if next is empty? Just a simple NULL check or what?

Comment: All zeros and all nulls would work. node foo[100] = { 0 } ;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure:

```
node x[4] = { {0, NULL}, {1, NULL}, {2, NULL}, {3, NULL} };
```

Even this should be fine:

```
node y[4] = { {0, y + 1}, {1, y + 2}, {2, y + 3}, {3, NULL} };
```

Comment: But what if I have 100,000 entries in my array?  Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: For 100,000 entries you'd probably initialising from persistent storage so efficiency would not be a concern as the performance would be io-bound. Kerrek SB's answer stands as 'most likely the best solution' in my opinion so gets +1.

Comment: @Bathsheba +1 I concur. There is no way via some magic declaration to initialize a sequence that increments ad-nausem to some declared upper-bound. Even a regular fixed trivial array, `int ar[N]` has the same restriction. The structure doesn't add extra complexity to that which is fundamentally impossible to begin with.

Comment: So what happens if I have an array of nodes and I check to see if the array indices are null?

Comment: @PaulthePirate: What are "array indices"?!

Comment: @PaulthePirate: Re 100000 entries: If you really want to *initialize* them, then you must spell out the initializer. If you're happy to assign the values after initialization, you can do it in a simple loop. (In C++ you could use templates to produce compact initializers, though.)

Comment: @KerrekSB Indices is the plural of index, so I just meant each node at a specific index.