# C ignoring const qualifier infront of structure

Tags: c, keil

I am trying to create an array of const structs, but i Keep getting

```
error initializer element is not a compile time constant
```

I am using keil IDE.
this is strange because my struct is a const, here is an example:

```
typedef const struct{
     CRGB color;  // CRGB is another struct
     void (*myfunc)(int);
}myProfile;


myProfile profile1 = { ....... }; // initialized struct

myProfile profiles[1] = { profile1 }; // error occurs here
```

even if I use
`const myProfile profile1 = { ..... };`

to initialize the struct, i still get the same errors.

I can find my way around it but I really want to understand what is going on. Thanks.

Comment: The initializer must be a *constant expression* which is a stronger condition than just a variable with `const` qualification.   In fact a variable is never a constant expression.

Comment: can you give me an example of what you mean for clarity @M.M I could do something like this `#define profile1 (myProfile){.....} ` what other options do I have?

Comment: Be wary of using `const` in a typedef (you're braver than I am using it there).  You could use `myProfile *profiles[1] = &profile1;`, initializing the pointer in the array with the constant address the other profile.  This might get you a result you can live with; you might add `const` qualifiers to the pointers.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan, you are right. But in this case, the profiles are meant to be constant anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because you try to initialize the array with a variable, which is not a constant (= a fixed value known at compile time), as M.M mentioned in the comments.

If you want to create a default value for your structure, you could do as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13716957).

Building on that answer, you would initialize a table with:

```
MyStruct instances[2] = {MyStruct_default, MyStruct_default};
```

Which is a shortcut for:

```
MyStruct instances[2] = { {.id = 3}, {.id = 3} };
```

Note that for a structure composed of multiple members, you can leave some blank and they should be set to 0 most of the time.