# Linked List: last pointer not NULL

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to insert an entry at the start of a linked list, so if the list was empty before, the next of the last inserted node should obviously be 0/NULL.
I just can't figure out why that isn't the case in my code.

I've already searched for answers but all I could find was setting list->head to 0, which I did in `struct _list`.

## list.cpp

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "list.h"

struct _node
{
    void *data;
    Node *next;
};

struct _list
{
    Node *head = nullptr;
};

List *list_create()
{ 
    List *list = (List *)malloc(sizeof(List));
    list->head = nullptr;
    return list;
}

void list_add(List *list, void *data)
{
    Node *current = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));

    current->data = data;
    current->next = list->head;
    list->head = current;
}
```

Comment: `malloc` does not do _anything_ with allocated memory (including initializing it to zero), so your `list_create` creates a list with undefined `head`. You should zero it manually. I suspect you're actually using C++ compiler because default values are [prohibited in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716913/default-value-for-struct-member-in-c), whilst allowed in C++ (but then you shouldn't be using C functions to allocate data).

Comment: 1. The prefix `_` is reserved for compiler implementations. 2. You never initialize `_node` instances properly with `NULL` for `data` or `next`, thus you shouldn't wonder.

Comment: You are in C++, use objects!

Comment: Did you just allocate a pointer in list_create, so your pointer points to an invalid pointer (which it incorrectly thinks is an invalid List)? Constructors would be a lot easier.

Comment: Also you should post a very short main which demonstrates the problem, so it is a [mcve]

Comment: You include "list.h" and use different names for the struct in this file, so I'm assuming that was a typo in creating this question. And wouldn't that be a stack, not a list? (because you insert at the front)

Comment: Don't use `malloc` in C++. Also don't use `NULL` or `0` for null pointers, use `nullptr`.

Comment: Since you are using C++, why aren't you using `std::list`?

Comment: @Eljay I'm still a beginner in C or C++ (though I have always been pretty sure I'm programming in C) and I have never used : or ::

Comment: Ahhh, then you could probably really use a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) on C++.

Answer (score 1):

malloc allocates memory. It does not call a constructor. So this will result in allocated memory for a "list_type" but it will contain uninitialized garbage.

```
Node *current = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

But that is okay for now, because you follow it up by initializing everything.

```
current->data = data;
current->next = list->head;
```

[deleted section where I lecture you about using an object for encapsulation for maintainability]

Now let's look at your list type:

```
struct List
{
    Node *head = 0;
};
```

Default values in the class (struct) declaration are applied in any constructor. But malloc is not a constructor, nor does it call a constructor. It just gets the memory needed. So if you malloc sizeof(List) you will NOT get anything initialized.

However, you don't even do that. You allocate space for another pointer to a list. So list_create gives you a pointer to some allocated memory for another pointer to random garbage (which is not a List, nor would it be valid if it were allocated). Although I suppose there is a chance that sizeof(List) and sizeof(List*) happen to be the same on your compiler, but it's UB if you just got lucky like that.

```
return  (List *)malloc(sizeof(List *));
```

You meant to do

```
List * list = (List *)malloc(sizeof(List));
```

So now you have something the size of a list, and you would then have to add this (because you didn't use a constructor, default or otherwise):

```
list->head = nullptr; // we're supposed to use "nullptr" now for type safety
return list;
```

but you don't have that. You just return the invalid pointer. So those are the two errors in that function.

[deleted section where I lecture you on using an object. You can get that from Samed Kahyaoglu's answer. But basically you have to go through a constructor or default constructor in order to use that default value in the header declaration of a class.]

To demonstrate that head was initialized:

```
int main() {
    List * list = list_create();
    list_add(list, nullptr);
    std::cout << list->head->next << std::endl;
}

output before fix:
CDCDCDCD

output after fix:
00000000
```

My compiler initializes malloc'ed data with CDCDCDCD in debug builds to make it easy to spot uninitialized data. Release builds would probably just have whatever random junk was there before.

Comment: incidentally, "new" does call a constructor, so new/delete is way better than malloc/free, but it's still bad in modern c++, unless entirely encapsulated within your class. So you can use new/delete on Node, but your problem was with List not getting constructed.

Comment: Well, thanks for the detailed answer, but sadly I've already tried `list->head = nullptr` in `list_create` but that didn't change anything (and yes, I changed the `sizeof(List *)` to `sizeof(List)`).

Comment: It does appear to fix the "why didn't it get initialized?" question, when I run it in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You are completely wrong, excuse me. This is how it should look like;

```
//first, define DataType or change DataType as you want to use

struct Node
    {
       DataType data;
       Node* next;
    };
struct List
{
    Node *head;
    void create();
    void add();
};

void List::create()
{
    head = NULL;
}

void List:add(DataType data)
{
   Node* newNode = new Node;
   newNode -> data = data;
   newNode -> next = NULL;
   Node* traverse = head;
   while(traverse){
      traverse->next; } // goes till finding last node then goes its next which is null
   traverse = newNode;
   return;
}
```

Comment: You can't have void data. List::create() should be List::List(). One colon before add is syntax error. List::add doesn't take an argument, so Node shouldn't have data. I know you're trying to avoid templates when you are first introducing objects but might want to adjust the approach.

Comment: data actually was a void* in OP

Comment: Yes I know i think it as a placeholder to make question generalized :))

Comment: I've never work with that data type, but you can put int, double, bool, char anything in the place of void.

Comment: I'm trying to help you out with actual errors. There's still that syntax error ...