# My linked list results in segmentation fault every time even though I cannot see a flaw

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I've been learning programming for some while now and I've seen this concept of "linked list" a few times and decided to give it a try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct cell {
    int number;
    struct cell* next;
} cell;

typedef struct {
    cell* head;
} cell_list;


void push_front(cell_list* list, int number) {
    printf("here\n");
    cell* n;
    printf("here2\n");
    n->number = number;
    printf("here3\n");
    n->next = list->head;
    printf("here4\n");
    list->head = n;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    cell_list* L;

    push_front(L, 5);
    push_front(L, 8);
    push_front(L, 19);

    cell* n = L->head;

    // this should print "19 8 5"
    while(n != NULL) {
        printf("Val: %d\n", n->number);
        n = n->next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
here
here2
here3
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I am looking for an answer to the following two questions:
(1) What is the correct way of doing this
(2) What is actually happening in my example? What is going wrong?

I am thinking that it is the compiler that fails to assign "struct cell* next" to be equal to "cell* head", etc.) OR that the FIRST allocated memory for head and the fist cell with the next property is at fault here.

Also similar posts and questions have answer to questions identical to mine however they fail at multiple points:
(1) the code example posted by OP is overly complex
(2) the code answers are good but... check 3
(3) the code answers and not explained, just "omg just use malloc you are casting voids everywhere"
(4) 1 - 3 results in a complete post with Q&A that is above my level. If your answer is "use malloc" or "the pointers point at random memory" or "you are pointing at null". Please explain because these are just programming jargon/language sentences that don't actually go into depth so that I, a beginner, can understand.

I am fully aware there are identical posts but none truly explain to a beginner like me why they allocate memory will malloc and cast the allocated space to become a linked list struct. If your answer is the same as in any of those posts, then please explain why this way is faulty and not just "This is how you do, there are 12893 posts about malloc and linked lists." I understand malloc and casting if that was not obvious but not how they properly fit in here and how my current program is created on the stack.

Comment: In the `push_front` function you have the pointer variable `n`. But *where does it point?* You forgot to allocate memory for your node.

Comment: *"I understand malloc and casting if that was not obvious but not how they properly fit in here and how my current program is created on the stack."* .. No you don't! And programs don't get created on stack!

Comment: And yes, *"use malloc"* is the apt answer!

Comment: A few links that provide basic discussions of pointers may help. [Difference between char *pp and (char*) p?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60519053/3422102) and [Pointer to pointer of structs indexing out of bounds(?)...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60639540/3422102) (ignore the titles, the answers discuss pointer basics) (however, nice effort on your question time spent formatting your code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the function `push_front`,

```
cell* n;
```

is a pointer of type `cell` and as David C Rankin rightly said it is uninitialized and currently holds an indeterminate address as its value until you initialize it by assigning a valid address. It does not point to a memory of type `cell` just like that until you make it point to a `cell` type.

Use malloc to allocate memory. You can refer the manual page for [malloc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html).

```
cell *n= malloc(sizeof(cell));
```

The very next thing your code should do is to check if call to malloc has successfully allocated memory or not and some error handling if memory is not allocated.

```
if(NULL == n)
{
    //! handle memory allocation error here
}
```

You also need to free this memory once you are done using it, and make the pointer point to null.

```
free(n);
n = NULL;
```

Based on your critical rant/comment at the end of original post, let me explain the code you wrote to you.

```
void push_front(cell_list* list, int number)
{
    /// This print helps you understand where the code is.
    printf("here\n");
    /// This declares is a pointer variable pointing to a `cell` type. 
    /// Not yet pointing since not initialized.
    cell* n;
    /// This print helps you understand where the code is.
    printf("here2\n");
    /// Tries to assign value of 'number' to 'number' variable present in 
    /// some memory accessed as data type `cell` via a pointer. 
    /// But wait, is pointer really pointing to a valid memory location 
    /// that can be access as `cell` type? NO!
    n->number = number; // You try to sit in a chair which isn't there, you fall!
    printf("here3\n");
    n->next = list->head; // You try to sit on a chair which isn't there, you fall!
    printf("here4\n");
    list->head = n; // This is a different problem as of now. 
                    // With 'n' not initialized, list->head also get
                    // corrupted since assigned with a garbage value. 
}
```

Also, in your `main()` function,

```
cell_list* L;
```

and then you invoke

```
push_front(L, 5);
```

In this function, you do the following:

```
n->next = list->head;
```

You design does not consider if `list->head` is initialized or not. If it is `NULL` you just made `n->next` point to NULL.

I understand and agree to the fact that a lot of people find pointers hard to understand and use correctly. I'll suggest that you first get comfortable with pointers overall (in general) and then go for implementing data structures with them. We all started there! You can start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37549595/4228131).

Comment: `"is a pointer of type cell"` that is *uninitialized* and currently holds an indeterminate address as its value until you initialize it by assigning a valid address. (nit -- I knew what you meant).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Agree with the comment, you & I both already know the fact that in my opinion you are master a pointers and explaining them to beginners and I am a fan! :-)

Comment: @WedaPashi You wrote: `//! handle memory allocation error here`. Is there a standard way of handling errors of memory allocation? Also I have never used malloc and it has failed, so what I am asking is both: (1) When does that happen and (2) What do I do besides messaging the user that the memory could not be allocated and exit?

Comment: Also I what is n->next for the first cell? The second cell should hold the first cell because its mem. address should be stored in the list->head, but that is list->head before I assign it the first cell's address? Also uninitialized?

Comment: Oh ok I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870038/uninitialized-pointers-in-code) post that explains that uninitialized pointer point towards garbage memory and will pass NULL check. I will simply have to initialize that value. I also found this [stackexchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716913/default-value-for-struct-member-in-c) post that said that structs cannot be initialiezed in the way I want to but directly after I create my list I can set the head to NULL, which is nice! Thanks a lot for the help! :)

Comment: @pointersarehard: I am glad that you have gone through multiple threads and have developed an understanding. This is the way we learn! Coming to the point of handling errors in `malloc()`.. There is little you can do about it, thats precisely why people recommend against using dynamic memory allocation in a lot of critical applications (best example would be a microcontroller-based embedded system). Ideally, I'd first want to check why `malloc()` failed in the first attempt itself. You need to check how much heap memory is configured for usage. `malloc()` borrows memory from heap section.

Comment: Contd... so in a nut-shell, if `malloc` fails, it means you can't borrow anymore from heap section unless you return the memory you have borrowed. So, if it starts failing after certain iterations, then you are not `free`ing it. If it fails in the first go itself, then your heap is not configured to be long enough, again this case is very commonly faced by beginners programming embedded systems. Usually, an embedded project toolchain has a provision to configure how much bytes of the RAM you want to reserve as heap. If it is set to zero, `malloc()` will fail for sure in the first go itself.

Answer (score -1):

You have to allocate memory for nodes using malloc.
Here is the updated code, I have tested it, it is working fine :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct cell {
    int number;
    struct cell* next;
} cell;

typedef struct {
    cell* head;
} cell_list;


void push_front(cell_list* list, int number) {
    printf("here\n");
    cell* n = malloc(sizeof(cell));
    printf("here2\n");
    n->number = number;
    printf("here3\n");
    n->next = list->head;
    printf("here4\n");
    list->head = n;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    cell_list* L = malloc(sizeof(cell_list));

    push_front(L, 5);
    push_front(L, 8);
    push_front(L, 19);

    cell* n = L->head;

    // this should print "19 8 5"
    while(n != NULL) {
        printf("Val: %d\n", n->number);
        n = n->next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to copy the whole program for your answer. All you really need is a single line of code to show the change.

Comment: @haresh this results in "segmentation fault 11" because n is never equal to NULL so when it is done counting the numbers pushed onto the cell list, it access void/NULL/whatever memory and dies.