# Error: "expected ‘:’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘}’ " and "struct has no member named"

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors, initialization, typedef

I cannot spot any missing bracket. What's the problem?

```
#ifndef PROCINFO_H_
#define PROCINFO_H_
#include <linux/limits.h>
#include <elf.h>

 enum boolean {f,t};

typedef struct {

    enum boolean fileHdr = 0;
    enum boolean programHdr=0;
    enum boolean sectionHdr = 0;
    enum boolean info = 0;
    enum boolean def = 0;
} procInfo;

typedef struct {
    char filename[NAME_MAX]; 
    procInfo info;
} procFile;


#endif /* PROCINFO_H_ */
```

Errors:

```
expected ‘:’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘}’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘=’ token  
make: *** [src/subdir.mk:20: src/elfViewer.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You don't have a missing bracket. You have `=` inside a struct definition. That is not possible in C. You can only assign values in variable definitions. There is no such thing as a default value for types in C.

Comment: For future questions please post the complete error message. It should include the exact location where the error is detected.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [default value for struct member in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716913/default-value-for-struct-member-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not initialize data members of a structure in C moreover in a typedef declaration as you are doing

```
typedef struct {

    enum boolean fileHdr = 0;
    enum boolean programHdr=0;
    enum boolean sectionHdr = 0;
    enum boolean info = 0;
    enum boolean def = 0;
} procInfo;
```

You need to write

```
typedef struct {

    enum boolean fileHdr;
    enum boolean programHdr;
    enum boolean sectionHdr;
    enum boolean info;
    enum boolean def;
} procInfo;
```

When an object of this type will be defined you may provide an initialization for it as for example

```
pricinfo info = { 0 };
```